# Accessing the script for a Google Sheets spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have a bunch of custom functions for a Google Sheets spreadsheet (access via Tools -> Script Editor...) that were working fine. At some point I decided to back up my functions by saving a copy of the script.
Now when I click Tools -> Script Editor... I get:

Select a project to open

Copy of myspreadsheet
myspreadsheet

Create a new project

The spreadsheet now alternates between the two scripts in an unpredictable fashion, using an old version of the same functions, then switching. How can I designate which one it should use? I can't even work out how to delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects

> #### Deleting a container-bound project
>
> 1. Open your container-bound project using the appropriate method above.
> 2. Select File > Delete.
> 3. Click Yes to delete the project.